# laravel doesn't return state param in session attributes

Tags: session, laravel, session-cookies, laravel-socialite

I use laravel version 5.1.4 and "laravel/socialite":"v2.0.8" When I try to social login I get this error `InvalidStateException in AbstractProvider.php line 183:` error. it is very interesting that it works on my macbook pro. But it doesn't work on windows chrome browser. I tried to find problem and I think I found. When I die dump laravel_session, laravel session doesn't return state parameter here is returned params.

```
 protected function hasInvalidState()
    {
        if ($this->isStateless()) {
            return false;
        }
        $session = $this->request->getSession();
        dd($session);
        dd($this->request->input('state'));
        return ! ($this->request->input('state') === $session->get('state'));
    }
```

This is the picture that I get on my macbookpro

[image: macbookpro chrome]

And this is on the windows.

[image: windows chrome]

Comment: Any luck, i have the same problem